# Image isn't loading to webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

I want a logo on my webpage but it isn't loading for some reason. Here's my code to include it in my html file:

```
<img src="IMG_4772.jpg" alt="Logo">
```

Here's what my file organization looks like: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IskmD.png)

Does anybody see where I'm going wrong? If it helps, I'm running a local server using Flask (python3 "filename" in terminal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image in the `static` folder and use `url_for`.

```
<img src="{{url_for("static",filename="IMG_4772.jpg")}}" alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<img src="./IMG_4772.jpg" alt="Logo">
```

"./" gets the current path.

Comment: This didn't work, thank you though